# How to pass parameter in spark submit which does not start with spark

Tags: shell, apache-spark

We can use `--conf spark.app.country=EARTH` to send parameters to source code in spark submit shell command. But for configurations like `oracle.net.tns_admin` and `java.security.egd` they do not start with spark. So, how do you send these parameters?

With out using extraJavaOptions can I send these as I do not want to send these like env parameters

Comment: Have you tried this? What happens when you try?

Comment: @DNA I tried putting non spark configuration in separate file and use  --properties-file, but the spark is not picking them up, unless they start with spark. Something like this  "spark.oracle.net.tns_admin"

Answer (score 0):

Spark `conf` arguments are designed specifically for Spark configuration (keys that you might otherwise place in `spark-defaults.conf`).

There are not to be used with generic properties (although it is fine to use `spark` prefix with your custom config as long as it doesn't clash with the actual Spark configuration).

If you want to provide generic configuration it makes sense to use Spark independent utilities, specific to your language of choice.